# Is it possible to filter and Dataframe by two conditions?

Tags: python, pandas

I am wondering if there is a way to filter a column in a dataframe with two conditions

```
matches_df = matches_df[matches_df['similairity'] < 0.9999999 AND matches_df['similairity'] > 0.9 ]
```

Comment: replace the and with &.  and yes, it is possible to filter a column in a dataframe with two conditions. share some sample data if u can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we can do that. Your code itself will work with a little modification.

1. Replace `AND` to `&`
2. Wrap the two conditions with braces.

```
matches_df = matches_df[(matches_df['similairity'] < 0.9999999) & (matches_df['similairity'] > 0.9)]
```

Hope it helps :)